# Inject environment variable into GitHub action with statement

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

I'm writing a GitHub action to build protocol buffers code and push it to another repository after building:

```
name: Release Go

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
env: 
  GEN_OUT_DIR: ./gopb
  GEN_PROTO_DIR: ./protos

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.18.3
      - name: Install Protoc
        uses: arduino/setup-protoc@v1
      - name: Install protoc-gen-go
        run: |
          go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@latest
          go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
      - name: Generate Go
        run: |
          mkdir -p $GEN_OUT_DIR
          echo "Compiling..." && find $GEN_PROTO_DIR -type f -name "*.proto" -exec protoc --go_out=$GEN_OUT_DIR --go-grpc_out=$GEN_OUT_DIR {} \;
          echo "Add Omitempty..." && find $GEN_OUT_DIR -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e 's/,omitempty.*enable-default/"` /g'
      - name: Release Go
        uses: cpina/github-action-push-to-another-repository@main
        env:
          SSH_DEPLOY_KEY: ${{ secrets.GO_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY }}
        with: 
          source-directory: ${{ env.GET_OUT_DIR }}
          destination-github-username: 'my_user'
          destination-repository-name: 'my_repo'
          target-branch: main
```

This relies on [github-action-push-to-another-repository](https://cpina.github.io/push-to-another-repository-docs/index.html) action. The issue I'm having is that this action fails because `source-directory` is empty. However, I'm injecting the value from the environment variable and it works in other places. How can I inject the value of an environment variable into the `with` clause for another action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if this is a typo issue.

You inject `GEN_OUT_DIR`, but are using `GET_OUT_DIR` which would be empty.

```yaml
env: 
  GEN_OUT_DIR: ./gopb
```